# Is it important to support all web browsers when doing web development?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser, web

May be a vague question but I was wondering on the importance and necessity to support all web browsers functionality when creating websites, I do come across a lot of issues with the infamous `Internet Explorer` which nowadays has almost become obsolete as everybody hates it, but people however still use it and it becomes a headache when you can't get the same `CSS` or formatting to apply to different browsers. `Chrome` and `Firefox` don't seem to give me problems but every version of `IE` that comes out seems to have a different way of doing things which we have to adhere to in order to get my websites to display how I want.

Wanted to ask any experienced web developers if it is actually necessary to ensure your websites display properly and the same on each browser? I actually don't take `IE` into consideration when doing websites I only test my websites on more popular browsers such as `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Safari` web and mobile. Is this a bad thing?

Comment: Actually, this is a primarily opinion-based question. It depends on many things whether or not to support different browsers.

Comment: How are chrome, Firefox, and safari more popular than IE? Or did you mean among Web developers?

Comment: http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1 (if statistics here aren't false, IE is most popular browser, yet).

Answer (score 1):

It is a vague question. And one we can't easily answer generically, as it will vary from project to project.

In an attempt to do so, however, the answer is "**yes, absolutely--unless there are valid reasons no to**"

The valid reasons not to, however, tend to be limited, but some off the top of my head:

- it's being built for a proprietary system (say...iPhones only--meaning maybe you can leverage all of mobile Webkit's abilities and not have to worry too much about graceful degredation)
- Because older versions of IE sucks. We all know this, but we're finally at a point where people are beginning to see it as a legitimate argument for not being fully cross-browser compliant. Older versions of IE tend to require an extra amount of work-around code which a) takes time b) money and c) is a maintenance headache.
- No one visiting the site uses it. This isn't a great excuse, but it can be valid. If no one is visiting the site using some obscure browser that hasn't been updated in several years, then why cater to it?

In fact, to summarize that last two bullets, I'd maybe say this:

- will supporting browser x require additional time, effort and non-proprietary code? If so, consider not supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

Understand it this way :

A website is just a platform to convey some information...now, if you want to show your information in same manner across all medium ( *web-browser* )....then, yes, you need to support all the mediums....else Cinderella can be rendered as beast too!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on who you expect your users to be. This depends on age, country, job and even politics if you are to beleve [TIME.com](http://science.time.com/2014/01/09/can-time-predict-your-politics/). If you have a conservative or older userbase you better support IE. Young, hip liberals are more likely to use Chrome/Firefox.

Internet explorer had about an 20% user-share in 2013 according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Desktop_and_mobile_browser_usage).

This is just my opinion but I see 20% as a lot. That doesn't mean that I have to have everything looking exactly the same in IE as in Chrome/Firefox. But it has to look decent, and absolutely not broken.

Comment: you can't take everything you read on Wikipedia as gospel. Most surveys show IE with 40-50% market share. It is still spread across 4-5 versions Hopefully with the death of XP enterprises will start upgrading from IE 8 to 11 soon.

Comment: 20% is a lot but you need to split that up between IE6, 7, 8, 9, 10, etc. And then you need to decide how much extra effort time and money goes into supporting each one of those.

Comment: @Chris Love I think those surveys can't include mobile devices. Or everyone not on a mobile device will be on IE since mobile is about to pass desktop usage soon. That leaves IE with 20-25% market share.

Comment: So is my Surface a mobile device or a laptop? I take it everywhere...But I use it like a laptop, or to watch tv, or read books and blog posts like an iPad...And yes they include mobile, but again every survey is different and how they calculate distributions, etc. Some do not count China for example and they have one of the largest computer market shares.

Comment: Fine, so IE has a bigger market share than I realize. I do however still think it's very important to support it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. But you should not worry about browsers, but instead support standards. When you support actual standards you will support all browsers. If you are worried about a feature not being supported or only partial support then you need to feature detect and react accordingly, either a polyfil or ignoring the functionality.